# Using factorials to find combinations

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, math, recursion, combinations

So, this is a two part question but based on the same project.  I am trying to write a small program that can illustrate how a computer can quickly crack a password, using a brute force attack.  It only has three inputs:  A check box to denote if it should use integers, a check box to denote if it should use letters, and a textbox to enter the password to be cracked.  It then outputs the number of combinations.  Here is my code:

```
dim a,b,c,d,P as double
'Using the following formula:
'P(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!)
'Let's assume we are just using numbers, so n = 10
'r = the count of characters in the textbox.

a = factorial(n)
b = factorial(r)
c = (n - r)
d = factorial(c)
P = a / (b * d)
Output = "With a password of " & r & " characters and " & n & " possible values, the number of combinations are " & P 
Me.RichTextBox1.Text = Output & vbCrLf

Function factorial(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
     If n <= 1 Then
        Return 1
     Else
        Return factorial(n - 1) * n
     End If
End Function
```

So, let's assume I'm only looking at the characters 0-9, with the following number of characters in a password, I get:

```
P(10,1) = 10!/(1! * (10-1)!) = 10
P(10,2) = 10!/(2! * (10-2)!) = 45
P(10,3) = 10!/(3! * (10-3)!) = 120
P(10,4) = 10!/(4! * (10-4)!) = 210
P(10,5) = 10!/(5! * (10-5)!) = 252
P(10,6) = 10!/(6! * (10-6)!) = 210
P(10,7) = 10!/(6! * (10-7)!) = 120
```

You can see the number of combinations goes down, once it gets past 5. I assume this is right, but wanted to check before I present this.   Is this because the total number in the pool remains the same, while the sample increases?

My second question is about how to consider a password to crack that repeats numbers.  Again, let's assume that we are just pulling from digits 0-9.  If the sample size it two (lets say 15), then there are 45 possible combinations, right?  But, what if they put in 55?  Are there still 45 combinations?  I suppose the computer still needs to iterate over every possible combination, so it would still be considered 45 possibilities?

Comment: Your probably shouldn't use combinations because they don't depend on order so for example 12 is same as 21 for a password this probably isn't desired. Other than that P(n, k) =P(n, n-k) which explains why after five it all repeats.

Comment: Ah, so use permutations, not combinations?

Comment: Actually it's pretty simple: the number of different passwords with a length of n characters, with each character having p possibilities is: p^n. So for a password with two digits it's 10^2=100.

Comment: Not regular permutations though, if there are n characters and k positions then the formula is pow(n, k) so for example if you consider only digits and a 2digit number you get pow(10,2)=100. Idk if they are still permutations they are called variations with repetition in my country.

Comment: Yes, because you would have to account for replacement, right?  Just because you have a pool of 10 characters (0-9) doesn't mean you can't pull more than 10 items from the pool.  That's why you need replacement?

Comment: There in no good reason to use the formula `P(n,k) = n!/k!` to literally compute `P(n,k)` as the ratio of two factorials. For example, `P(100,2) = 9900` (easy enough that I did it without a calculator) shouldn't require the computation of astronomically large numbers (which will overflow what a double can handle). Why compute numbers just to almost instantly cancel them? Instead, just multiply the numbers that are actually part of the answer. Use something like `product = 1` followed by `For i = n To n-k+1 Step -1 product = product * i Next`.

Comment: Incidentally, that is one of the worst ways to calculate a factorial. It is only used to demonstrate recursion. Just do the multiplications without recursion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think you would be better served in the math exchange site. This has little to do with coding and everything to do with pure combinatorics.